# Unable to save a model object with Spring MVC and AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody()
public Map<String,Object> save(@ModelAttribute Invoice invoice) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {   
         productService.save(invoice);

         data.put("message", "Ok");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        data.put("message", ex.getMessage());
    }

    return data;
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class Invoice {
  private Double amountPaid;
  private Double amountDue;

  private List<InvoiceItem> items;

  public List<InvoiceItem> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  ...
}

public class InvoiceItem {
  private String productCode;
  private String productName;

  ...
}
```

jQuery code to send invoice details to the controller:

```
var paid = jQuery("#amountPaid").val();
var due = jQuery("#amountDue").val();

var data = [{
            productCode : "productCode",
            productName : "productName"
        }, {
            productCode : "productCode",
            productName : "productName"
        }];

var r = confirm("Submit invoice?");
if (r == true) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/product/save',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      amountDue: due,
      amountPaid: paid,
      items: data
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) { ... },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { .. }
  }); 
}
```

However, I get the following error when the data is submitted:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'items[0][productCode]' of bean class [Invoice]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'items[0][productCode]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [productCode]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a `application/json` request from your client script and use `@RequestBody` in controller to parse the JSON request. Following is the idea:

change `@ModelAttribute` to `@RequestBody` in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody()
public Map<String,Object> save(@RequestBody Invoice invoice) throws IOException
```

And change the client script to send a json request with `contentType: "application/json"` and `JSON.stringify`:

```
var data = {
        amountDue: due,
        amountPaid: paid,
        items: [
        {
            productCode : "productCode",
            productName : "productName"
        }, 
        {
            productCode : "productCode",
            productName : "productName"
        }]};

$.ajax({
  url: '/product/save',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  type: 'post',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) { ... },
  error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { .. }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, plz leave your email contact. I want to learn this framework spring and my batis i am starting in this.

Comment: in this case I helped me a lot because I'm learning a new framework for myself, I don´t have money for online course or particular teacher :8, I see you have experience, if I could spend some books I greatly appreciate it. please

Comment: There is lots of online resource for spring and mybatis. For example, [Spring Started Guides](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) and [mybatis Started Guides](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html). If you find problems after some try, you can also post question to SO.